# NVim Omnisharp-Vim autocomplete on tab not working

Tags: autocomplete, omnisharp, neovim

Using NeoVim and autocomplete is not completing the suggestion.

For example:

I get the popup when start typing a word such as `public`.
I just start typing `pu` and then the dialogue pops up to suggest the full word, but when I hit tab is just adds a tab after the word with out completing.

Here is by init.vim if it helps

```
"set this to 1 to use ultisnips for snippet handling
let s:using_snippets = 0

" vim-plug: {{{
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

Plug 'omnisharp/omnisharp-vim'

" Mappings, code-actions available flag and statusline integration
Plug 'nickspoons/vim-sharpenup'

" Linting/error highlighting
Plug 'dense-analysis/ale'

" Vim FZF integration, used as OmniSharp selector
Plug 'junegunn/fzf'
Plug 'junegunn/fzf.vim'

" Code Snippets
Plug 'SirVer/ultisnips'

" Autocompletion
Plug 'prabirshrestha/asyncomplete.vim'

" Colorscheme
Plug 'gruvbox-community/gruvbox'

" Statusline
Plug 'itchyny/lightline.vim'
Plug 'shinchu/lightline-gruvbox.vim'
Plug 'maximbaz/lightline-ale'

" File Navigation
Plug 'preservim/nerdtree'

" Snippet support
if s:using_snippets
  Plug 'sirver/ultisnips'
endif

call plug#end()
" }}}
"
" Line Numbers
:set number relativenumber

:augroup numbertoggle
:  autocmd!
:  autocmd BufEnter,FocusGained,InsertLeave * set relativenumber
:  autocmd BufLeave,FocusLost,InsertEnter   * set norelativenumber
:augroup END

" fuzzy file search
set runtimepath^=~/.vim/bundle/ctrlp.vim

" Settings: {{{
filetype indent plugin on
if !exists('g:syntax_on') | syntax enable | endif
set encoding=utf-8
scriptencoding utf-8

set completeopt=menuone,noinsert,noselect,preview

set backspace=indent,eol,start
set expandtab
set shiftround
set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=-1
set tabstop=8
set textwidth=80
set title

set hidden
set nofixendofline
set nostartofline
set splitbelow
set splitright

set hlsearch
set incsearch
set laststatus=2
set noruler
set noshowmode
set signcolumn=yes

set mouse=a
set updatetime=1000
" }}}

" Colors: {{{
augroup ColorschemePreferences
    autocmd!
    " These preferences clear some gruvbox background colours, allowing transparency
    autocmd ColorScheme * highlight Normal     ctermbg=NONE guibg=NONE
    autocmd ColorScheme * highlight SignColumn ctermbg=NONE guibg=NONE
    autocmd ColorScheme * highlight Todo       ctermbg=NONE guibg=NONE
    " Link ALE sign highlights to similar equivalents without background colours
    autocmd ColorScheme * highlight link ALEErrorSign   WarningMsg
    autocmd ColorScheme * highlight link ALEWarningSign ModeMsg
    autocmd ColorScheme * highlight link ALEInfoSign    Identifier
augroup END

" Use truecolor in the terminal, when it is supported
if has('termguicolors')
  set termguicolors
endif

set background=dark
colorscheme gruvbox
" }}}

" ALE: {{{
let g:ale_sign_error = '•'
let g:ale_sign_warning = '•'
let g:ale_sign_info = '·'
let g:ale_sign_style_error = '·'
let g:ale_sign_style_warning = '·'

let g:ale_linters = { 'cs': ['OmniSharp'] }
" }}}

" Asyncomplete: {{{
let g:asyncomplete_auto_popup = 1
let g:asyncomplete_auto_completeopt = 1
" }}}

" Sharpenup: {{{
" All sharpenup mappings will begin with `<Space>os`, e.g. `<Space>osgd` for
" :OmniSharpGotoDefinition
" let g:sharpenup_map_prefix = '<Space>os'
let g:sharpenup_map_prefix = ',os'

let g:sharpenup_statusline_opts = { 'Text': '%s (%p/%P)' }
let g:sharpenup_statusline_opts.Highlight = 0

augroup OmniSharpIntegrations
  autocmd!
  autocmd User OmniSharpProjectUpdated,OmniSharpReady call lightline#update()
augroup END
" }}}

" Lightline: {{{
let g:lightline = {
\    'colorscheme': 'gruvbox',
\    'active': {
\      'right': [
\        ['linter_checking', 'linter_errors', 'linter_warnings', 'linter_infos', 'linter_ok'],
\        ['lineinfo'], ['percent'],
\        ['fileformat', 'fileencoding', 'filetype', 'sharpenup']
\      ]
\    },
\    'inactive': {
\      'right': [['lineinfo'], ['percent'], ['sharpenup']]
\    },
\    'component': {
\      'sharpenup': sharpenup#statusline#Build()
\    },
\    'component_expand': {
\      'linter_checking': 'lightline#ale#checking',
\      'linter_infos': 'lightline#ale#infos',
\      'linter_warnings': 'lightline#ale#warnings',
\      'linter_errors': 'lightline#ale#errors',
\      'linter_ok': 'lightline#ale#ok'
\     },
\    'component_type': {
\      'linter_checking': 'right',
\      'linter_infos': 'right',
\      'linter_warnings': 'warning',
\      'linter_errors': 'error',
\      'linter_ok': 'right'
\     }
\   }
" Use unicode chars for ale indicators in the statusline
let g:lightline#ale#indicator_checking = "\uf110 "
let g:lightline#ale#indicator_infos = "\uf129 "
let g:lightline#ale#indicator_warnings = "\uf071 "
let g:lightline#ale#indicator_errors = "\uf05e "
let g:lightline#ale#indicator_ok = "\uf00c "
" }}}

" OmniSharp: {{{
let g:OmniSharp_server_stdio = 1
let g:OmniSharp_translate_cygwin_wsl = 1
let g:OmniSharp_popup_position = 'peek'
if has('nvim')
  let g:OmniSharp_popup_options = {
  \ 'winhl': 'Normal:NormalFloat'
  \}
else
  let g:OmniSharp_popup_options = {
  \ 'highlight': 'Normal',
  \ 'padding': [0, 0, 0, 0],
  \ 'border': [1]
  \}
endif
let g:OmniSharp_popup_mappings = {
\ 'sigNext': '<C-n>',
\ 'sigPrev': '<C-p>',
\ 'pageDown': ['<C-f>', '<PageDown>'],
\ 'pageUp': ['<C-b>', '<PageUp>']
\}

if s:using_snippets
  let g:OmniSharp_want_snippet = 1
endif

let g:OmniSharp_highlight_groups = {
\ 'ExcludedCode': 'NonText'
\}
" }}}
"

imap <c-space> <Plug>(asyncomplete_force_refresh)
inoremap <expr> <Tab>   pumvisible() ? "\<C-n>" : "\<Tab>"
inoremap <expr> <S-Tab> pumvisible() ? "\<C-p>" : "\<S-Tab>"
inoremap <expr> <cr>    pumvisible() ? asyncomplete#close_popup() : "\<cr>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was being foolish, I should have used Ctl+P or Ctl+N.
Noob.
Closing ticket